# Disable trailing slash redirect in next.js

Tags: next.js, trailing-slash

I have some pages that are `/hello.html` and should not be changed and others that are `/hello`, and `/hello/`. In real life are a bit different, but I would like to don't redirect from `/hello` to `/hello/` or viceversa. Each url is very specific and should not be changed. I was wondering if this feature can be disabled in next.js somehow.

I have a custom server and middleware if any code needs to go there..

Comment: I have the same issue as you. Currently, it doesn't look like Next JS has the capability to disable it completely: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15148